# Linear gradient in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

This code works exactly as expected in every desktop browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari) and also in Firefox on Android. I don't have an iOS device to test with - I'd be curious to know what happens on an iPhone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
<title>Background</title>
<style>
html {
    height:100%;
    background:linear-gradient(red, blue) no-repeat fixed;
}
.wrapper {
    min-width:590px;
    padding:20px;
}
.box {
    height:250px;
    width:550px;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'><div class='box'></div></div>
<div class='wrapper'><div class='box'></div></div>
<div class='wrapper'><div class='box'></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Live demo: https://misterneutron.com/lgtest/

The "no-repeat" attribute isn't even necessary, but just makes this demo even more clear. In short, it provides a red-to-blue linear gradient background that fills the viewport, and stays put if you have to scroll vertically or horizontally to see all of the green boxes. Firefox on Android flickers a bit, but gets the correct result. But in Chrome on Android, the background linear gradient scrolls with the content, leaving a white background. Without the "no-repeat" attribute, it actually repeats the background, apparently ignoring the "fixed" attribute.

Not surprisingly, the same thing happens with a background image (https://misterneutron.com/bgtest/). Same page code, but replace the html styling with:

```
html {
    height:100%;
    background: url('aspectWide.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I've tried all types of alternates - 100-percenting things like height and width on html and body, putting the background on the body rather than the html, and so on. Nothing seems to change the behavior. Does anyone know how to beat this browser bug, or do I just have to wait for some future release? I could do some browser-sniffing and eliminate the background if it's Chrome on Android, but ugh.

There are threads about similar issues, but most are several years old, and address much older browser versions. And not one of the suggested workarounds has succeeded.

Edit: Another data point. The problem is much less severe with a repeating background: https://misterneutron.com/bgtest2/. But the "fixed" attribute is still being ignored. Much easier to live with than the original problem, however!

Comment: So far, the only response from Google has been, "We don't support fixed backgrounds in Chrome on Android." They can't make it work smoothly (neither can Firefox - it's a little jerky), so it appears they'd rather have a horribly broken page, instead.

Comment: Indeed... Where did you find/get a response from them regarding this? I guess the other option is to have a body that doesn't scroll, and wrap everything in a scrollable wrapper?

Comment: My original bug report got merged into another. No progress, even with the latest Chrome Dev, v.66. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521555